# How to filter the package list by package name part or regex

Tags: package, list-packages, filtering

Via `M-x list-packages` I can view a list of installable and installed packages. Great! But how can I filter this list by a portion of the package *name*?

---

PS: I know about `package-menu-filter`, but for me this command filters only on the package *description*, not the package *name*. E.g. when I filter on `lsp-mode` I get packages like `lsp-scala`, etc, but *not* what I was looking for, namely `lsp-mode`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/ n` (M-x package-menu-filter-by-name) does exactly what you want, it filters only the package name, e.g., `/ n lsp-mode` gets only the lsp-mode package.

> / n runs the command package-menu-filter-by-name (found in
> package-menu-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
> in `package.el'.
>
> It is bound to / n,    .
>
> (package-menu-filter-by-name NAME)
>
> Filter the "*Packages*" buffer by NAME.
> Show only those items whose
> name matches the regular expression NAME.  If NAME is nil or the empty
> string, show all packages.

You can clear the filter via `/ /`.

I'm testing with Emacs 27.1. Not sure which version of Emacs added the feature.

Comment: `C-h N' will tell you (it's new in emacs-27)

Comment: Cool. - Gives me a reason to upgrade all my Emacses! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try `C-h P` (M-x describe-package), it allows you filter by package names through the minibuffer. If you use helm-mode, it looks like

[image: search lsp]

And in the `*Packages*` buffer, use Isearch and/or Occur, for example, to search packages start with lsp, use

```
M-s o ^ +lsp
```

M-s o is M-x occur.

[image: occur lsp]

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it might be all there is... (The `isearch` method is what I use day-to-day, but feels a bit cumbersome - that's why I asked the question in the first place.)